# Laravel 8. Route::resource с динамическим параметром. Роут в шаблоне

Tags: php, route, resources, laravel-8

Здраствуйте.
Стоит задача редактировать заявки на мероприятия.
event_id - ID мероприятия. Он динамический.

```
Route::resources(['events_reg/{event_id}' => EventsUsersRegistrationsController::class]);
```

При таком раскладе все ок. По ссылке /admin/events_reg/100 я получаю список пользователей зарегистрированных на 100-е мероприятие. Но как в blade-шаблоне прописать роут, например, для редактирования конкретной заявки?
Пробовал такие варианты:

```
{{route('events_reg/{event_id}.edit', $user_id)}}
{{route('events_reg/{100}.edit', $user_id)}}
{{route('events_reg/100.edit', $user_id)}}
```

Результат такого вида - ошибка:

```
Route [events_reg/{event_id}.edit] not defined
Route [events_reg/{100}.edit] not defined
Route [events_reg/100.edit] not defined
```

Пробовал принудительно:

```
/admin/events_reg/100/1/edit
```

Результат:

```
Route pattern "/admin/events_reg/{event_id}/{{event_id}}" cannot reference variable name "event_id" more than once.
```

Вобшем как правильно сделать Route::resources с динамическим параметром ? (или возможно неправильный подход у меня.)

---

Еще заметил, что теперь при переходе на другие роуты (статьи, новости..) появляется такая же **текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом**ошибка:

```
Route pattern "/admin/events_reg/{event_id}/{{event_id}}" cannot reference variable name "event_id" more than once.
```

Направьте на правильный путь, знатоки!

Comment: в шаблоне нужно указывать имя (название) маршрута, а не путь. Потому что путь вы можете поменять со временем, а вот имя можно (нужно) не менять, т.к. это вещь используемая сугубо в коде.

Comment: Передайте ID нужного элемента из контроллера в Blade, и вызывайте route с этой переменной в шаблоне. Вьюшка по сути - это отображение, в контроллере - логика, вот и пусть он определяет какой ID отобразить вьюшке.

Answer (score 0):

Решил инным путем - создал отдельный resource для заявок на мероприятие и в нем настроил правильные редиректы

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]